# How can arrange the date of a column in ascending order using R

Tags: r, plotly, tidyverse

I have a dataset containing details about date, continent and continental_sum(total death  in each continent) which is show in the image.

[image]

But the date column is not arranged in an order, how can I arrange should I use lubridate?

```
typeof(continental_death_total$date)
[1] "character"
```

```
library(lubridate)
continental_death_total%>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date))
```

> Tried the above code and the date column gets arranged in ascending order

[image]

but when I tried to plot a barplot it shows different values.

The code for barplot

```
df <- continental_death_total

fig <- df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~continent,
    y = ~continental_sum,
    frame = ~date,
    type = 'bar',
    mode = 'markers',
    showlegend = F
  )

fig
```

[image]

> Output of Bar Plot

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput` instead of images? So we can help you better.

Comment: how do you use dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your edge x with date and add varible color with continent, if you want a grouped barplot:

```
df <- continental_death_total

fig <- df %>%
  plot_ly(
  x = ~date,
  y = ~continental_sum,
  color = ~continent,
  type = 'bar',
  mode = 'markers',
  showlegend = F
)

fig
```